# Python: why driver.find_element_by_class_name gives no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Currently I'm working with Selenium trying properly identify elements using 'Inspect' from Chrome.
In certain cases some of my buttons to click defined only by class, however certain classes are failed to be found using''' driver.find_element_by_class_name '''.

Here is the peace of code I retrive with Inspect from Chrome:

```
  <td class="x-toolbar-cell" id="ext-gen1328" role="menuitem">
  <table id="ImportMenuSmartExpReport" cellspacing="0" class="x-btn grayBtn x-btn-text-icon" role="presentation" style="width: auto;">
   <tbody class="x-btn-small x-btn-icon-small-left">
    <tr>
     <td class="x-btn-tl"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
     <td class="x-btn-tc"></td>
     <td class="x-btn-tr"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="x-btn-ml"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
     <td class="x-btn-mc"><em class="" unselectable="on"><button type="button" id="ext-gen1329" class=" x-btn-text menu_import2">Import Expenses</button></em></td>
     <td class="x-btn-mr"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="x-btn-bl"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
     <td class="x-btn-bc"></td>
     <td class="x-btn-br"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

1. I need to click on 'Import Expenses' button which is part of 'x-btn-text menu_import2' class. I can not use XPATH or ID here, because it's dynamic value for different submission forms it has different values.
   So I try to use class: ''' driver.find_element_by_class_name(" x-btn-text menu_import2") '''
   However, it gives me back an error:

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in 
driver.find_element_by_class_name(" x-btn-text menu_import2")
File "C:\Users\ataranov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
File "C:\Users\ataranov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
File "C:\Users\ataranov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\ataranov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
(Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.90*

2. At the same time I can find'x-toolbar-cell' class :'''driver.find_element_by_class_name("x-toolbar-cell")''' without any problems.

- What is the problem here to find class I need with '''find_element_by_class'''? Why it works for one class, but does not for another one?
- Is it somehow related to the fact that '''x-btn-text menu_import2 ''' is enclosed to other class? If so, how find class what are wrapped to other's classes?
- Any other way to find object in this case, like using button text title 'Import Expenses'

Comment: What your refering to is actually multiple class names. You can use css selector or use one of the two class names to reference it.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.x-btn-text.menu_import2")
```

Multiple class names need to be dealt like so . class_name only deals with a single class identifier.

To find by text you could.

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[.='Import Expenses']")
```

Comment: Thank you! indeed I could find object using both methods you have mentioned. However I fail to interact with thouse objects using ''' click()'''. In both cases it fails saying that 'element not interactable':


Any tips how to deal with this further?

Comment: and the same element is clickable when it's serached by_id.
So not really getting the difference why the search by_xpath and css_selector gives object back as 'not interactable' making click(); not working

Comment: I've also noted that for objects found `by_xpath` and by `by_css_selector` following tests gives me **False**:
`print("Element is visible? " + str(button_id.is_displayed()))`
While object found `by_id` give me **True** and they are interactable

Comment: Try using a webdriver for expected conditions element to be clickable.